# reload pickerView with sync

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have a pickerView with two col(colA colB) and when colA changed colB must reload with new data, then I notice that when I want to update colB with new data by `.reloadComponent()` method and the method is async, this will lag to display for 5~6 sec, but when I touch the colB it will update immediately.

So I want to update colB with sync but something wrong happened

```
DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                pickerView.selectRow(0, inComponent: 1, animated: false)
                pickerView.reloadComponent(1)
            }
```

and I got some error message with

`Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`

code section

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        ...
        if component == 0{
            picker1DIdSelect=row

            DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                pickerView.selectRow(0, inComponent: 1, animated: false)
                pickerView.reloadComponent(1)
            }
            print("RELOAD")
        }

    }
```

or anyone have the other way to fix it?

Comment: Do not use `sync` or `async`. There is no reason for either.

Answer (score 0):

First, you must not call `DispatchQueue.main.sync` from within an delegate callback, because these already run in the main thread.

Second: as I understand, if the user selects something in `colA`, you change the model for `colB` and want to refresh the data. Is your model correct; does it provide the correct values in `numberOfComponents` and `pickerView(:numberOfRowsInComponent:)`?

Third, you could try to change the order of the `selectRow` and `reloadComponent` calls. Although I'm almost sure that this should not influence anything.

Comment: i know main thread is sync, but the method `.reloadComponent()` is not, that's the problem with me, and without `DispatchQueue.main.sync` the code works fine, just a little lag for display(it does not refresh until next touch event), so I think I am correct at "the Second point"

Comment: `reloadComponent` will trigger a reload (e.g. redisplay) of the `UIPickerView` in the next event loop - and this is what you want. It should *not* wait until any other touch event or so, it should just redisplay the data. I would suggest to set breakpoints at the `UIPickerViewDataSource` methods and check the values for component and row to see if there is some mismatch with the model.

Comment: ok...after I upgrade my Xcode to latest version, the simulator go more smooth than before and the problem was disappear(without change or use any sync method), I think it may be something bug or crash. But also thanks you for answer my question ^^